# How do I get duplicate rows?

Tags: teradata

I have got a Teradata table. I have attached a part of the table for reference. 
I need to print out the rows which have exactly the same values

Table Values:

```
id    Name    City    Country

1     John    Berlin  Germany
2     Mike    Warsaw  Poland
3     Neil    London  England
1     John    Berlin  Germany
2     Mike    Warsaw  Poland
4     Alan    Moscow  Russia
```

The output that I am expecting is

```
id    Name    City    Country

1     John    Berlin  Germany
2     Mike    Warsaw  Poland
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be solved your problem.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName
group by id, Name, city, country
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

@ManguYogi's solution works fine (and is probably more efficient), but I wanted to add another solution because it's a rare case that `except all` can be useful:

```
select * from mytab
EXCEPT ALL 
select distinct * from mytab
```

If a row exists more than twice it will be returned multiple times. Of course, if you're interested in this you can simply add the `count` to the @ManguYogi's Select.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- this will select all duplicate rows
select * from johns_table
qualify row_number() over (partition by id order by id) > 1
```